# Why won't a List of complex types bound to TextBoxes in a table show changes to the model in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have run into an issue that seems pretty simple, but I have not been able to find a solution. I have created a ReportModel object that is the model in the view. The ReportModel contains a list of FinancialHistory objects. I populate the objects and display them in a table of textboxes within a form in the view using default binding (This works correctly). The user can then submit the form to refresh the FinancialHistory objects from a different datasource, replacing what was previously in the list with the new results. When the new results are returned, I can see that the model contains the expected new values, but when the HTML is rendered, the original amounts still appear. If the new results contains more objects than the original list (as shown in the example code), the added rows do appear with the correct values. So, if the original had 2 objects and the refreshed list has 3, the resulting HTML shows the first 2 rows with the old values and a 3rd row with the new values.

Here are the models:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<FinancialHistory> FinancialHistories { get; set; } 
}

 public class FinancialHistory
{
    public FinancialHistory()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

In the Home/Index view, I use HTML.TextBoxFor() to bind the properties of each FianancialHistory object in the list to textboxes in a table.  Here is the Index view:

```
@model SimpleExample.Models.ReportModel

<form id="FormSave" method="post" name="FormSave" action="/Home/Refresh">

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccountNumber)

<table class="table" style="width: 95%">
    <tr>
        <td >Date</td>
        <td >Amount</td>
    </tr>

    @{
        if (Model.FinancialHistories != null)
        {                   
            for (int index = 0; index <= Model.FinancialHistories.Count - 1; index++)
            {              
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinancialHistories  [index].TransactionDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @readonly = "true" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinancialHistories[index].TotalAmount, "{0:#,#.00}", new { @readonly = "true" })</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FinancialHistories[index].Id)</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
     }

</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Refresh" class="submit" />
</form>
```

For this example, my action methods in the controller are very simple.  Initially, the Index method populates the list with 2 FinancialHistory Objects. The Refresh method replaces the original 2 objects with 3 new objects, with different amounts.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ReportModel reportModel = new ReportModel();

        reportModel.AccountNumber = "123456789";

        IList<FinancialHistory> financialHistories = new List<FinancialHistory>();
        financialHistories.Add(new FinancialHistory
                                    {
                                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                        TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2010"),
                                        TotalAmount = 1000.00M
                                    });

        financialHistories.Add(new FinancialHistory
                                    {
                                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                        TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("4/1/2011"),
                                        TotalAmount = 2000.00M
                                    });

        reportModel.FinancialHistories = financialHistories;

        return View(reportModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Refresh(ReportModel reportModel)
    {
        FinancialHistoryRepository financialHistoryRepository = new FinancialHistoryRepository();

        IList<FinancialHistory> financialHistories = new List<FinancialHistory>();
        financialHistories.Add(new FinancialHistory
                                    {
                                        Id = Guid.Empty,
                                        TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2010"),
                                        TotalAmount = 1111.11M
                                    });
        financialHistories.Add(new FinancialHistory
                                    {
                                        Id = Guid.Empty,
                                        TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("4/1/2011"),
                                        TotalAmount = 2222.22M
                                    });
        financialHistories.Add(new FinancialHistory
                                    {
                                        Id = Guid.Empty,
                                        TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2012"),
                                        TotalAmount = 3333.33M
                                    });

        reportModel.FinancialHistories = financialHistories;

        return View("Index",reportModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that for the first two financial histories (with `TotalAmount` of `1000` and `2000`), when you edit their values and submit the form their values return to their original state when the view is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how HTML helpers work and is by design. When rendering they are first looking in the ModelState for values and after that in the model. You are modifying the values of your model in the POST controller action, but the ModelState values still contain the old values which will be used. If you want to modify values of your model in a POST action you should remove the original values from the ModelState if you intend to redisplay the same view:

```
public ActionResult Refresh(ReportModel reportModel)
{
    // clear the original posted values so that they don't get picked up
    // by the helpers
    ModelState.Clear();

    FinancialHistoryRepository financialHistoryRepository = new FinancialHistoryRepository();
    ...
    return View("Index",reportModel);
}
```