# C# RemoveAt keeps removing the last item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can't seem to get the list to remove the correct item.
I've put breakpoints in the code to test if the id is the correct index with shipment.shipmentfreight[id] within the Immediate Window and it shows the correct list item, but it always removes the last item.

In my view model I have a list of ShipmentFreightLine declared as:

```
public List<ShipmentFreightLine> shipmentfreight { get; set; }
```

I have a call back that removes the line that returns the new partial view:

```
public virtual ActionResult ShipmentNewFreightLineRemove(int id,NewShipment shipment)
{
    int cnt = shipment.shipmentfreight.Count();

    if (id >= 0 && cnt != 1 && id <= cnt)
    {
        shipment.shipmentfreight.RemoveAt(id);
        //shipment.shipmentfreight.RemoveAt(shipment.shipmentfreight.IndexOf(shipment.shipmentfreight[id]));
        //shipment.shipmentfreight.Remove(shipment.shipmentfreight[id]);
        //shipment.shipmentfreight[id]
    }

    return PartialView("ShipmentNewFreightLineEdit", shipment);

}
```

As you can see I've commented out different variations that I have tried and each one removes the last item in the list.

What am I missing?

I am coding in VS2012 ASP.NET MVC using C#.

---

Any help would be aprreciated

As requested by Kirk the id field is from an anchor

```
<a href="#" class="deleteRow" onclick="RemoveFreightLine(0);">Remove</a>
```

Which calls this javascript function

```
function RemoveFreightLine(index) {
    var ShipmentData = $('#fShipmentNew').serialize();
    var url = "/Tracking/ShipmentNewFreightLineRemove/" + index
    $.post(url, ShipmentData,
        function (data) {
            $("#dNewFreightLines").html(data);
        });
}
```

These all have the correct id in them so i don't believe its the cause

---

I traced the view and found that it is removing the correct item in the list but the view is showing the old data

```
    <table id="tFreight" class ="tblFreight">
    <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.shipmentfreight.Count; i++)
    {
            <tr>
                <td>@(i+1)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].Pieces, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].Description,new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtareasmall"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].WeightPerPiece, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].ActualWeight, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].Length, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].Width, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.shipmentfreight[i].Height, new { autocomplete = "off", @Class = "txtboxsmall",maxlength ="3"})</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="deleteRow" onclick="RemoveFreightLine(@(i));">Remove</a></td>
                <td>@Model.shipmentfreight[i].Description</td>
            </tr>
    }
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

The last cell was for debugging purposes and does display the correct information.
I am thinking its some quirk with TextBoxFor that I don't know about.

Basically the last cell is showing the correct data from the new list but anything in the TextBoxFor is showing the old list data.
Any ideas on why I am getting this behavior?

---

Looks like this was a problem with the ViewData and not the List.

This seems to fix the problem:

```
ViewData = null;
```

or

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Found the answer with [Why won't a List of complex types bound to TextBoxes in a table show changes to the model in MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720942/why-wont-a-list-of-complex-types-bound-to-textboxes-in-a-table-show-changes-to) and [TextBoxFor Helper retains previous value even when model value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221691/textboxfor-helper-retains-previous-value-even-when-model-value-is-empty)

As with all things...Finding the real cause is key to finding the answer.

Comment: Everything is predicated on the value of `id`, yet you show no code indicating its value.

Comment: Won't this only ever remove anything if there is only 1 item in the list and `id=0` (`id=1` should throw an exception?)?

Comment: Kirk - its value is a value set by a javascript call and its value is correct but I will post it

Comment: Austin - Its built to remove down to 1 and no further.  However i do think it should be `if (id >= 0 && cnt != 1 && id <= cnt-1)` but i was originally toying with making the id the line number and not the index of the list item